# A formula for splitting a column into 2? All values from even-number-rows will go to second column, odd-number-rows will go to 3rd column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I like to do the following.

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | B |
| B | C | D |
| C |  |  |
| D |  |  |

Right now I am using `=MOD(ROW(A2),2)` in one column and `=IF(A2=0,A2,"")` follow by filter. Can it be `simplyfied` in to a single array formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In B2 try

```
=FILTER(A2:A, ISEVEN(ROW(A2:A)))
```

and in C2

```
=FILTER(A2:A, ISODD(ROW(A2:A)))
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can also try this single formula

```
=index(vlookup(sequence(counta(A2:A)/2, 2, 2, 1), {row(A2:A), A2:A}, 2, 0))
```

[image]